# MouseKeyHook application lags on boot and can't be closed

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, mousekeyhook

I've written a simple auto clicker using MouseKeyHook.

The reason I use MouseKeyHook is to detect global left clicks throughout Windows OS.

Although, when I run the .exe, the software lags on the click and after a while I can't seem to hit the 'X' button anymore and the application crashed my windows or slows down everything.

I am making this software to test our game, but this is not really helping :P

The code for the software can be found below:

```
using Gma.System.MouseKeyHook;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rapid_Fire
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    #region structs
    /// <summary>
    /// Structure for SendInput function holding relevant mouse coordinates and information
    /// </summary>
    public struct INPUT
    {
        public uint type;
        public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Structure for SendInput function holding coordinates of the click and other information
    /// </summary>
    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public int mouseData;
        public int dwFlags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    };
    #endregion

    // Constants for use in SendInput and mouse_event
    public const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0x0000;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

    private const int INTERVAL = 10;

    private bool m_fire = false;
    private bool m_close = false;
    private int m_counter = INTERVAL;
    private INPUT m_input = new INPUT();
    private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Subscribe();
        InitAutoClick();

        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(formClosed);
    }

    private void Subscribe()
    {
        m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
        m_GlobalHook.KeyPress += GlobalHookKeyPress;
        m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt += GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
    }

    private void GlobalHookKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 'q') m_fire = false;
    }

    private void GlobalHookMouseDownExt(object sender, MouseEventExtArgs e)
    {
        m_fire = true;
        RapidFire();
    }

    private void InitAutoClick()
    {
        m_input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        m_input.mi.dx = 0;
        m_input.mi.dy = 0;
        m_input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        m_input.mi.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        m_input.mi.mouseData = 0;
        m_input.mi.time = 0;
    }

    private void RapidFire()
    {
        while (m_fire && !m_close)
        {
            if (m_counter <= 0)
            {
                // ClickLeftMouseButtonSendInput();
                m_counter = INTERVAL;
            }
            m_counter--;
        }
    }

    private void ClickLeftMouseButtonSendInput()
    {
        // Send a left click down followed by a left click up to simulate a full left click
        SendInput(1, ref m_input, Marshal.SizeOf(m_input));
        m_input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref m_input, Marshal.SizeOf(m_input));
    }

    private void formClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_fire = false;
        m_close = true;
        Unsubscribe();
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        m_GlobalHook.MouseDownExt -= GlobalHookMouseDownExt;
        m_GlobalHook.KeyPress -= GlobalHookKeyPress;
        m_GlobalHook.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Once it gets into RapidFire() then the show is over, your UI thread starts burning 100% and there will be no more UI events.  So the m_fire and m_close variables cannot change.  Never hang the UI thread.

Comment: So I gotta run it on a new thread? :)

Comment: Writing sensible code would be the first thing to consider.  Nobody can suggest anything better for this code, other than Random.Next()

Comment: It's very sensible.. On left click the script goes to RapidFire. Once the q button is hit, it will stop, because it will set m_fire to false, which will interrupt the loop. I don't see what's not sensible about that..

Comment: `Once the q button is hit` ... the message will never be processed because the UI thread is busy in a loop. All UI messages (key presses, mouse clicks) are suspended until after `RapidFire` is finished. You probably want to use a `BackgroundWorker` or separate thread for the `RapidFire`.

Comment: Fixed it with a new thread, thank you all :D Since I got no real answer, I can't mark it as good solution :( Comments can't be marked as solved answer thing..

Comment: You can post and accept your own answer. That way the question doesn't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the script by doing it another way. Turns out I had to attach it to a left mouse button down event :D

Here the script is:

```
using Gma.System.MouseKeyHook;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rapid_Fire
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SendInput(int nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

    #region structs
    /// <summary>
    /// Structure for SendInput function holding relevant mouse coordinates and information
    /// </summary>
    public struct INPUT
    {
        public uint type;
        public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Structure for SendInput function holding coordinates of the click and other information
    /// </summary>
    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public int mouseData;
        public int dwFlags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    };
    #endregion

    public const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0x0000;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

    private const int TIMES_CLICK_FIRE = 25;

    private bool m_fire = false;
    private INPUT m_input = new INPUT();
    private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_Events;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SubscribeGlobal();
        InitAutoClick();

        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(formClosed);
    }

    private void SubscribeGlobal()
    {
        Unsubscribe();
        Subscribe(Hook.GlobalEvents());
    }

    private void Subscribe(IKeyboardMouseEvents events)
    {
        m_Events = events;
        m_Events.MouseUp += OnMouseUp;
        m_Events.MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
    }   

    private void InitAutoClick()
    {
        m_input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        m_input.mi.dx = 0;
        m_input.mi.dy = 0;
        m_input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        m_input.mi.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        m_input.mi.mouseData = 0;
        m_input.mi.time = 0;
    }

    private void Log(string text)
    {
        if (IsDisposed) return;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        m_fire = true;

        Thread thread = new Thread(RapidFire);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void RapidFire()
    {
        while (m_fire)
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                ClickLeftMouseButtonSendInput();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        m_fire = false;
    }

    private void ClickLeftMouseButtonSendInput()
    {
        SendInput(1, ref m_input, Marshal.SizeOf(m_input));
        m_input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref m_input, Marshal.SizeOf(m_input));
    }

    private void formClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Unsubscribe();
    }

    private void Unsubscribe()
    {
        if (m_Events == null) return;
        m_Events.MouseUp -= OnMouseUp;
        m_Events.MouseDown -= OnMouseDown;

        m_Events.Dispose();
        m_Events = null;
    }
}
}
```